# Soundproofing windows against air traffic noise

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

We're currently renting an attic apartment under one of Heathrow's main flight paths and unfortunately have only double glazed velux windows. The aircraft noises are fairly loud and I'm looking to reduce this.

As it's rented accommodation I'm looking at fairly cheap and non destructive options (e.g. replacing windows).

Right now I'm thinking about how sound studios eliminate outside noise, so would Acoustic foam over the inside of the windows block some of the sound?
http://www.cutfoam.co.uk/acoustic.html as I would be able to just stick these up with sticky back tape.

Any ideas of how to eliminate some noise would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, figure out how the majority of noise is getting into the interior.  Is it really coming through the windows? Or is it coming through the roof and ceiling and walls?

Windows are the hardest to sound deaden, but you imply you are good with acoustic foam on the windows?!  What about bricking (in a removable way) over the window?

An existing space can be quieted substantially with *heavy* draperies from ceiling to floor.  Not just on the windows, but on the walls.

A drop ceiling installed under an existing ceiling also helps.  That also allows placement of additional insulation.

No idea what the limits are for UK rentals, but they seems to be a lot more loosey-goosey than in the U.S.!

Comment: Looks like the majority comes through the windows (Double Glazed - you would expect triple under a busy flightpath) as foam is rather cheap I may try it and see. Are you saying drapes from ceiling to the floor?

Comment: @user3082823:  Yes, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=heavy+floor+to+ceiling+drapes&safe=off&biw=1429&bih=743&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV_JDEpfrLAhVN3GMKHThiDHgQsAQIUw&dpr=0.9#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=heavy+sound+deadening+floor+to+ceiling+drapes).